# Python loop print variable + string

Tags: python

I am am looking to print a static string stored in the list while looping .. e.g

```
List = ["Hello",
        "Hi",
        "Testing"]

for example in list:
    print (List + "World")
```

Can anyone guide me on this one?

Comment: `print(example + "World")` instead of `(List + "World")` and also change line 5 to be `for example in List:`

Comment: Capitalization matters and as importantly, don't name things 'list' since that's a built-in class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't shadow a built-in name. Use a unique name.

```
my_list = ["Hello", "Hi", "Testing"]
for example in my_list:
    print (example + " World")
```

You'd probably want a space in your string concatenation, otherwise you'll get `HelloWorld`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I understand, what you're asking is to print an item of the list with 'World', right?
This is very simple, let's see:

```
 list = ['Hello','Hi','Testing']
 for item in list:
     print(item + ' World!')

 >>> 'Hello World!'
 >>> 'Hi World!'...
```

Hope this helps :)